# Latest value of compared date range? (SQL/Snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have values in Table-A like:

```
Patient|Invoice|Date
A,111,2021-02-01
A,222,2021-01-01
B,333,2021-03-01
B,444,2021-02-01
C,555,2021-04-01
C,666,2021-03-01
```

And values in Table-B like:

```
Patient|Value|Date
A,2,2021-01-05
A,3,2021-01-05
A,3,2021-02-05
B,1,2021-02-05
B,1,2021-03-05
C,6,2021-01-01
```

And I want to join the two tables such that I see the most recent cumulative sum of values in Table-B as-of the Date in Table-A for a given Patient.

```
Patient|Invoice|Latest Value|Date
A,111,5,2021-02-01
A,222,0,2021-01-01
B,333,1,2021-03-01
B,444,0,2021-02-01
C,555,6,2021-04-01
C,666,6,2021-03-01
```

How would I join these two tables by date to accomplish this?

Comment: Hey Mark - your Stack Overflow story shows that you've asked many questions in the past few months, but accepted no answer. Please look out for the people that are out here to help you and give them at least some feedback. Note that I'm not the first person to tell you, back in October Mikhail said in an answer to you "have you tried? did this work for you? if it is - consider voting up - this motivates us to answer your next questions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step seems like a basic SQL join:

```sql
select patient, invoice, sum(value), date
from table1 a
join table2 b
on a.patient=b.patient
and a.date=b.date
group by patient, invoice, date
```

But instead of a plain `sum()` you can apply a `sum() over()`:

```sql
select patient, invoice
  , sum(value) over(partition by patient order by date)
  , date
from table1 a
join table2 b
on a.patient=b.patient
and a.date=b.date
group by patient, invoice, date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that first we need to calculate the time intervals when the invoice is valid (using [LAG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html) function), then calculate the cumulative [SUM](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/sum.html).

```sql
WITH A AS (
  SELECT Patient, Invoice, Date, IFNULL(LAG(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Patient ORDER BY Date), '1900-01-01') AS LG
    FROM Table_A
)
SELECT DISTINCT A.Patient, A.Invoice, IFNULL(SUM(B.Value) OVER(PARTITION BY A.Patient ORDER BY A.Date), 0) AS Latest_Value, A.Date
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN Table_B AS B 
    ON A.Patient = B.Patient
   AND B.Date >= A.LG AND B.Date < A.Date
GROUP BY A.Patient, A.Invoice, A.Date, B.Value
ORDER BY A.Patient, A.Invoice, A.Date;
```